# Dynamical Horizontal View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-adapter, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to add views dynamically to a linear layout.

> I just need the following

From web service i will get category names and image URL and tried to add all the category to linear layout under horizontal view using **addview** function but only the last category were displayed.

> please see the picture below i need such a layout were marked with red rectangle portion have to load category with image dynamically, that portion should be scroll-able horizontally.

[image]

Comment: Please, before you vote down like a couple others here did, please comment and say what's wrong with the question, otherwise I can't improve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple create custom horizontal list view .use this to generate list view and use an array adapter to set data

here is my working example [enter link description here](https://github.com/jeekiran/horizontal-scroll-listview)

in you layout xml

```
<com.jeekiarn.horizontal_listview.HorizoantalListView
    android:id="@+id/hlvSimpleList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />


mHlvSimpleList = (HorizoantalListView) findViewById(R.id.hlvSimpleList);
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, mCustomData);

    // Assign adapter to HorizontalListView
    mHlvSimpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mHlvSimpleList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

> create custom horizontal list view like below 
>     and bind your adapter class to it

```
 package com.sujith.custom_layout;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;

public class GalleryHorizontal extends HorizontalScrollView{

private LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultTabLayoutParams;
private LinearLayout.LayoutParams expandedTabLayoutParams;


private LinearLayout tabsContainer;
 private Adapter adapter;
 private DataSetObserver dataSetObserver=new DataSetObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onChanged();
             reloadChildViews();
        }

    };
public GalleryHorizontal(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public GalleryHorizontal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public GalleryHorizontal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    setFillViewport(true);
//      setWillNotDraw(false);

    tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
    tabsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    tabsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    addView(tabsContainer);



}
public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
    if (this.adapter == adapter) return;
    this.adapter = adapter;
    if (adapter != null) adapter.registerDataSetObserver(dataSetObserver);
    reloadChildViews();
}

private void reloadChildViews() {
    tabsContainer.removeAllViews();
      if (adapter == null) return;
      int count = adapter.getCount();
      for (int position = 0; position < count; ++position) {
            View v = adapter.getView(position, null, this);
            if (v != null){

                tabsContainer.addView(v);

            }
        }

      tabsContainer.requestLayout();

}
```

}